# Selenium scraping with multiple urls

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Following my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235516/reformatting-scraped-selenium-table), i'm now trying to scrape multiple pages of a url (all the pages with games in a given season). I'm also trying to scrape multiple parent urls (seasons):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

url = ['http://www.oddsportal.com/hockey/austria/ebel-2014-2015/results/#/page/', 
       'http://www.oddsportal.com/hockey/austria/ebel-2013-2014/results/#/page/']

data = []

for i in url:
    for j in range(1,8):
        print i+str(j)        
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()        
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)        
        driver.get(i+str(j))


        for match in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div#tournamentTable tr.deactivate"):
            home, away = match.find_element_by_class_name("table-participant").text.split(" - ")
            date = match.find_element_by_xpath(".//preceding::th[contains(@class, 'first2')][1]").text

            if " - " in date:
                date, event = date.split(" - ")
            else:
                event = "Not specified"

            data.append({
                "home": home.strip(),
                "away": away.strip(),
                "date": date.strip(),
                "event": event.strip()
            })

        driver.close()
        time.sleep(3)
        print str(j)+" was ok"

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print df

# ok for six results then socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
# ok for two results, then infinite load
# added time.sleep(3)
# ok for first result, infinite load after that
# added implicitly wait
# no result, infinite load
```

At first I tried the code twice without either the implicit wait on line 14 or the sleep on 35. First result gave the socket error. Second result stalled with no error after two good scraped pages.

Then added the time waits as noted above and they haven't helped.

Since the results are not consistent, my guess is connection be reset between the end of the loop & next run. I'd like to know if that's a likely solution and how to implement. I checked the robots.txt of the site and can't see anything that prevents scraping after a set interval.

Secondly, say the scraper gets 90% of the pages, then stalls (infinite wait). Is there a way to have it retry that loop after x seconds so as to save what you've got and retry from the stalled point again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need to do is:

- reuse the same `webdriver` instance - do not initialize it in the loop
- introduce [Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) - this would definitely make the code more reliable and fast

Implementation:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import pandas as pd


urls = [
    'http://www.oddsportal.com/hockey/austria/ebel-2014-2015/results/#/page/',
    'http://www.oddsportal.com/hockey/austria/ebel-2013-2014/results/#/page/'
]

data = []

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for url in urls:
    for page in range(1, 8):
        driver.get(url + str(page))
        # wait for the page to load
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#tournamentTable tr.deactivate")))

        for match in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div#tournamentTable tr.deactivate"):
            home, away = match.find_element_by_class_name("table-participant").text.split(" - ")
            date = match.find_element_by_xpath(".//preceding::th[contains(@class, 'first2')][1]").text

            if " - " in date:
                date, event = date.split(" - ")
            else:
                event = "Not specified"

            data.append({
                "home": home.strip(),
                "away": away.strip(),
                "date": date.strip(),
                "event": event.strip()
            })

driver.close()

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                   away         date          event                home
0              Salzburg  14 Apr 2015      Play Offs     Vienna Capitals
1       Vienna Capitals  12 Apr 2015      Play Offs            Salzburg
2              Salzburg  10 Apr 2015      Play Offs     Vienna Capitals
3       Vienna Capitals  07 Apr 2015      Play Offs            Salzburg
4       Vienna Capitals  31 Mar 2015      Play Offs         Liwest Linz
5              Salzburg  29 Mar 2015      Play Offs          Klagenfurt
6           Liwest Linz  29 Mar 2015      Play Offs     Vienna Capitals
7            Klagenfurt  26 Mar 2015      Play Offs            Salzburg
8       Vienna Capitals  26 Mar 2015      Play Offs         Liwest Linz
9           Liwest Linz  24 Mar 2015      Play Offs     Vienna Capitals
10             Salzburg  24 Mar 2015      Play Offs          Klagenfurt
11           Klagenfurt  22 Mar 2015      Play Offs            Salzburg
12      Vienna Capitals  22 Mar 2015      Play Offs         Liwest Linz
13              Bolzano  20 Mar 2015      Play Offs         Liwest Linz
14        Fehervar AV19  18 Mar 2015      Play Offs     Vienna Capitals
15          Liwest Linz  17 Mar 2015      Play Offs             Bolzano
16      Vienna Capitals  16 Mar 2015      Play Offs       Fehervar AV19
17              Villach  15 Mar 2015      Play Offs            Salzburg
18           Klagenfurt  15 Mar 2015      Play Offs              Znojmo
19              Bolzano  15 Mar 2015      Play Offs         Liwest Linz
20          Liwest Linz  13 Mar 2015      Play Offs             Bolzano
21        Fehervar AV19  13 Mar 2015      Play Offs     Vienna Capitals
22               Znojmo  13 Mar 2015      Play Offs          Klagenfurt
23             Salzburg  13 Mar 2015      Play Offs             Villach
24           Klagenfurt  10 Mar 2015      Play Offs              Znojmo
25      Vienna Capitals  10 Mar 2015      Play Offs       Fehervar AV19
26              Bolzano  10 Mar 2015      Play Offs         Liwest Linz
27              Villach  10 Mar 2015      Play Offs            Salzburg
28          Liwest Linz  08 Mar 2015      Play Offs             Bolzano
29               Znojmo  08 Mar 2015      Play Offs          Klagenfurt
..                  ...          ...            ...                 ...
670       TWK Innsbruck  28 Sep 2013  Not specified              Znojmo
671         Liwest Linz  27 Sep 2013  Not specified            Dornbirn
672             Bolzano  27 Sep 2013  Not specified          Graz 99ers
673          Klagenfurt  27 Sep 2013  Not specified  Olimpija Ljubljana
674       Fehervar AV19  27 Sep 2013  Not specified            Salzburg
675       TWK Innsbruck  27 Sep 2013  Not specified     Vienna Capitals
676             Villach  27 Sep 2013  Not specified              Znojmo
677            Salzburg  24 Sep 2013  Not specified  Olimpija Ljubljana
678            Dornbirn  22 Sep 2013  Not specified       TWK Innsbruck
679          Graz 99ers  22 Sep 2013  Not specified          Klagenfurt
680     Vienna Capitals  22 Sep 2013  Not specified             Villach
681       Fehervar AV19  21 Sep 2013  Not specified             Bolzano
682            Dornbirn  20 Sep 2013  Not specified             Bolzano
683             Villach  20 Sep 2013  Not specified          Graz 99ers
684              Znojmo  20 Sep 2013  Not specified          Klagenfurt
685  Olimpija Ljubljana  20 Sep 2013  Not specified         Liwest Linz
686       Fehervar AV19  20 Sep 2013  Not specified       TWK Innsbruck
687            Salzburg  20 Sep 2013  Not specified     Vienna Capitals
688             Villach  15 Sep 2013  Not specified          Klagenfurt
689         Liwest Linz  15 Sep 2013  Not specified            Dornbirn
690     Vienna Capitals  15 Sep 2013  Not specified       Fehervar AV19
691       TWK Innsbruck  15 Sep 2013  Not specified            Salzburg
692          Graz 99ers  15 Sep 2013  Not specified              Znojmo
693  Olimpija Ljubljana  14 Sep 2013  Not specified            Dornbirn
694             Bolzano  14 Sep 2013  Not specified       Fehervar AV19
695          Klagenfurt  13 Sep 2013  Not specified          Graz 99ers
696              Znojmo  13 Sep 2013  Not specified            Salzburg
697  Olimpija Ljubljana  13 Sep 2013  Not specified       TWK Innsbruck
698             Bolzano  13 Sep 2013  Not specified     Vienna Capitals
699         Liwest Linz  13 Sep 2013  Not specified             Villach

[700 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Excellent, this works perfectly. Thank you very much. Edit: I tried put the driver instance back in the loop and its slow. Therefore initializing the instance for each loop != efficient. So `EC` improves reliability, but can you explain why? I've looked [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) and [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) but it's not easy to understand how they improve the delivery of info, other that waiting for expected element. How does EC work, in your words?

Comment: @noblerthanoedipus the wait and expected conditions are a good way to wait for certain conditions to be met on the page which helps to avoid hardcoded time delays and proceed as soon as the condition is met. Not sure if it helps in understanding. Thanks.